# Why KeyError exception getting thrown even though I'm catching it using try catch

Tags: python, exception, keyerror

Here's the code

```
class FancyTuple:
    mapping = {1:"first", 2:"second", 3:"third", 4:"fourth", 5:"fifth"}
    reverseMapping = {"first": 1, "second": 2, "third": 3, "fourth":4 , "fifth": 5}
    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._values = args
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):
            setattr(self, f"{self.mapping[i+1]}", arg)
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            index = self.reverseMapping[name] - 1
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'")
        
        try:
            return self._values[index]
        except IndexError:
            raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'")
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._values)
```

Here's the exception

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/3t/wf6fblsn3b9byqx75s_l8g300000gn/T/ipykernel_27328/2978799403.py in __getattr__(self, name)
     11         try:
---> 12             index = self.reverseMapping[name] - 1
     13         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'chal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/3t/wf6fblsn3b9byqx75s_l8g300000gn/T/ipykernel_27328/2705563914.py in <module>
----> 1 a.chal

/var/folders/3t/wf6fblsn3b9byqx75s_l8g300000gn/T/ipykernel_27328/2978799403.py in __getattr__(self, name)
     12             index = self.reverseMapping[name] - 1
     13         except KeyError:
---> 14             raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'")
     15 
     16         try:

AttributeError: 'FancyTuple' object has no attribute 'chal'
```

Comment: Just to mention that this looks very much like `collections.namedtuple`

Answer (score 1):

A KeyError is not being raised, an AttributeError is.

The hint is

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

If you don't want to raise [a chained exception (that stores that "cause")](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) (see "A similar mechanism works implicitly..."), explicitly `raise ... from None`:

```
except KeyError:
    raise AttributeError(f"...") from None
```